# Как заполнить форму данными из базы?

Tags: python, django

помогите пожалуйста решить проблему.

у меня есть форма. после её отправки данные записываются в базу данных. мне нужно чтобы при первой загрузке формы поля были заполнены теми данными, которые сейчас находятся в базе.

views.py:

```
def personal_data_page(request):            
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = PersonalDataForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid(): 
            #record in the database
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/changed/')
    else:
        form = PersonalDataForm()       #1

    t = loader.get_template('personal_data_page.html')
    c = RequestContext(request, {
        'form': form,
    })
    return HttpResponse(t.render(c))
```

models.py:

```
class UserProfile(User):
    email_address = models.EmailField(
        'Адрес электронной почты',
        max_length=50, 
        blank=True,
    )   
    other = models.TextField(
        'Интересы и увлечения',
        max_length=500,
        blank=False,
    )

    objects = UserManager()
```

personal_data_page.html:
    {% extends "page_base.html" %}

```
{% block title %}User profile - personal data{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
    <h2>personal data page</h2>

    {% for field in form %}
        {{ field.error }}
    {% endfor %}

    <form action="{% url 'views.personal_data_page' %}" method="POST">{% csrf_token %}
        {{ form.as_p }}

        <input type="submit" value="send" />
    </form>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Что значит

> при первой загрузке формы поля были заполнены теми данными, которые сейчас находятся в базе

Если вам нужно вывести какую либо запись из базы в качестве начальных данных формы, то у форм унаследованных от ModelForm есть свойство instance